# zend framework 2 projects conflict

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a home server with 2 sites zf2 plus doctrine in a structure like this: var/www/site1 and var/www/site2 i think i have a conflict with namespaces. On one of two projects(site1) i receive:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation\Target in /var/www/site2/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/Annotation/Target.php on line 31
```

what should i do to not try to load classes from other project?
Tank u.

Comment: i dont think it is related to namespaces. It should be a problem with set-up/autoload/bootstrap in the project. Take a look at your classmaps, your autoloading files, etc. Probably if you copy/pasted the project, you have any config file or anything inside vendor/autoloader, pointing to the doctrine in the old project, and also some other line pointing to the new doctrine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a while i figure out what goes to this, is opcache from php, once i disable all zf2 project goes well. i don't know how to adjust to work with opcache enable

Comment: You can disable opcache on a project by project basis, by using

`php_flag opcache.enable Off`

in a .htaccess file. And just to confirm, this was indeed the root cause of the Doctrine redeclare class errors in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you included the class `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation\Target` two times. It is difficult to say how you could achieve that.

Zend Framework 2 uses autoloading, so this type of error is typically impossible there. To install Doctrine, you use Composer dependency manager, and it creates all the autoloading configuration for you. But, if you then copy and paste the Composer-generated code in another project, you might have problem like yours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from hosts file one site were to 127.0.0.1 and other to 192.168.10.20 i change and everything work normal

Comment: Can you give us more details. I have the same problem!

Comment: look to my new answer to see if it's resolv you're problem too